# Forcing adobe reader to update root certificate providers

Tags: pdf, certificate, root, signed

We have C# code that digitally signs PDFs with a certificate. The PDFs are sent to customers.

Depending on the installation of Adobe Reader on the client pc the customer will get a message that the signature is either correct or that the 'certification is unknown'.

When the certification is unknown, the installation of Adobe Reader on the client pc has no knowledge of the chosen root certificate provider. The root provider (in this case 'DigiNotar') has to be imported. On some machines adobe reader will ask whether this update must be installed and on some machines not.

My question:
Can we somehow force Adobe Reader to update the root certificate providers (pref without changing settings in Adobe Reader)?

Regards,

Michel